# Neo4jclient C# get all nodes and relationships to JSON

Tags: c#, json, neo4j, neo4jclient

I want to get all nodes and relationships to JSON. If i execute this in the neo4j-browser i get what i want. (http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/)

```
:POST /db/data/transaction/commit
  {"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH path = (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN path",
  "resultDataContents":["graph"]}]}
```

Using Neo4jclient in my ASP.NET application, and don't know how to translate that. I have checked the example project they have on their site, but it doesn't help me.

Eventually i will use the result to present it with d3. But i cant get the JSON to work.

Comment: Can you add more details about what exactly you can't do in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking to do something like: http://geekswithblogs.net/cskardon/archive/2013/07/23/neo4jclient-ndash-getting-path-results.aspx

The code on that page is for the older Cypher way - but aside from using `.Start` which you no longer need - it should work for you.